# Lyx modifying moderncv empty space

Tags: latex, lyx

I am new on latex and lyx. I have to realize a resume and used moderncv. Do you know how I can have the space behing my picture being reduced ? (The one hatched in red) . As everything is supposed to fit in one page with a cv, it is important for me.
Thanks for your help
[image]

```
%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Do}
\title{Title}
\address{adress}{city}
\mobile{+33 6 §§ §§ §§ §§}
\email{john.do@ens.psl.eu}
\photo[100pt]{Mii_Artwork.png}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Formation}

\cventry{2021/2022}{Master de Science cognitive}{Ecole normale supérieure rue d'Ulm}{Paris}{France}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problem? (we don't need your personal data, just replace it with some dummy names etc.)

Comment: I can't add a .lyx file to my post. I'll try to add the code behind my lyx document.

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack: add `\vspace{-1.5cm}` after `\maketitle` :
`

```
%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Do}
\title{Title}
\address{adress}{city}
\mobile{+33 6 §§ §§ §§ §§}
\email{john.do@ens.psl.eu}
\photo[100pt]{example-image}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\vspace{-1.5cm}

\section{Formation}

\cventry{2021/2022}{Master de Science cognitive}{Ecole normale supérieure rue d'Ulm}{Paris}{France}{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @PaulCharp You're welcome! And good luck with your application or whatever else you are writing the CV for!